# Importing data from excel into matlab (saving in an array)

Tags: excel, matlab, import, multiple-columns

I simply have X and Y values which are saved in columns in Excel, I want to use these values within my MATALB function m-file and save them automatically in an array.

i.e. I want column A in Excel to become an array 'xArray' in MATLAB and column B in excel to become an array 'yArray' in MATLAB.

How do I do this within code, so I don't have to manually import.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
FILE = 'data1.xls';
[NUM,TXT,RAW]=xlsread(FILE);
xArray = cell2mat(RAW(:,1));
yArray = cell2mat(RAW(:,2));
```

By column A and column B in the excel sheet, I am assuming you meant first and second columns respectively.

Comment: Thank you this works great, however where there are no values in the column it is being exported to MATLAB with nan (not a number) is there a way I can set this up to get rid of this or do I need to create an if statement ?

Comment: Would you like to make those NaNs as zeros instead? Use - "xArray(isnan(xArray))=0;" and same for yArray.

Comment: I understand this is because there are inputs elsewhere on the spreadsheet that are not necessary to this calc but are in other cases. Is there a way of importing so once it reaches a blank cell it stops?

Comment: No I need it to not contain a value, please see comment above.

Comment: Stops reading the excel file? Not possible inside MATLAB. MATLAB will read the excel in one go without any interruption. Of course you can specify ranges I think, to read sheet after sheet of an excel file. Go through this more info - http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html